# How to make algorithm which finding the largest profit?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem with the algorithm. I have an array in which the nth-element is the price of the action on day X. I have to find the largest possible profit from an array. I was trying to use reduce(), but I don't know exactly how. This exercise is a little bit hard for me, but I wanna know how to do that.

For e.g.

**Input:**
[9, 2, 6, 1, 6, 7]

**Output:** 10

**Description:**

You buy in the second day (share price = 2) and you sell the third day (share price = 6), so the profit 6-2 = 4. Then you buy them in the fourth day (share price = 1) and you sell the sixth day (share price = 7), so gain 7-1 = 6. Profit from two transactions 6 + 4 = 10

Comment: please provide your attempt/code

Comment: You can only sell one unit at a time?

Comment: First find the lowest value, then find the highest value. But at least try by yourself before asking.

Comment: @assoron Yes, Im not able to conclude transactions at the same time - ie I have to sell shares before re-buying.

Comment: @DiegoFrancisco I wrote that exercise is too hard for me, I need some help. I was trying by myself, but my code doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the local minimum or maximum first in an array and then get the profit.

> Find local min and max
>
> ```
> 2   6   1   8   2   3   6   7   9   1   5   6   2   7   9   5   1   3   4   7   6   2   4   8   6   4
>   <   >   <   >   <   <   <   <   >   <   <   >   <   <   >   >   <   <   <   >   >   <   <   >   >
>
> 2   6   1   8   2               9   1       6   2       9       1           7       2       8       4
> ```

```js
var data = [9, 2, 6, 1, 6, 7] ,
    localMinMax = data.reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
        if (!(r.length & 1) === a[i - 1] < v) {
            r[r.length - 1] = v;
        } else {
            r.push(v);
        }
        return r;
    }, []),
    result = 0,
    i = 0;

while (i < localMinMax.length) {
    result += localMinMax[i + 1] - localMinMax[i];
    i += 2;
}

console.log(result);
console.log(localMinMax);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can u explain me this part of code: (!(r.length & 1)

Comment: The `&` is a [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). You should generally not use them as they are uncommon and tend to be used just for "conciseness" disregarding readability.

Comment: it take the length of `r`, takes a [bitwise AND `&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND) with one, the result is either one, if then lenght is odd or zero, if even. the prepended [logical NOT `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT) returns a boolean negation of the value.

Comment: you may ask why, because this value is taken to compare with another comparison result if the previous value is smaller than the actual value.

Comment: @NinaScholz thank u, I'm wondering now what should I do in this situation: Input: [7,6,4,3,1], when there is no profit

Comment: in this case, you need to check if the array with min and max values is even.